# Migrate Kafka cluster to Azure Eventhubs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-eventhub, strimzi

My objective is to migrate data from a kafka cluster to Azure eventhub . I tried MirrorMaker2 , it works but it requires namespace level admin privileges to work as MirrorMaker creates some internal topic on the destination . Tried confluent replicator as well , that fails with a max message exceeded error when trying to send messages as simple as "abcd" . Please suggest some other connectors preferably from Microsoft or Confluent .

I looked up google and could not find anything useful. Is there any eventhub sink connector available to use with Strimzi Kafka Connect?

Comment: Strimzi is an operator for running and managing Apache Kafka. It uses the Apache Kafka open-source project and just provides additional tooling for it. Apache Kafka itself does not ship any connectors (apart from the File connectors which are mainly an example). Connectors live outside of the Apache Kafka project and you use them as plugins when deploying your Kafka Connect cluster. So in general, any connector for Apache Kafka should work with Strimzi - there are no special connectors for _Strimzi Kafka Connect_ and there is nothing special about Strimzi compatibility with Azure EventHubs.

Comment: @Jakub Small correction - MirrorMaker2 is also an included connector

Comment: Edited the post to clarify the issue.. Can you not create the necessary Mirrormaker topics on the destination? And, ignoring the example, are your source Kafka messages larger than the allowed record sizes for EventBus (thereby causing Replicator to fail)? If thats the case, then any other solution may fail as well unless you can increase allowed record size on the EventBus instance. Note: Replicator also requires at least one "internal topic" for `__confluent_license`

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Regarding creation of internal topics required by mirrormaker manually , we don't have control on the eventhubs namespace , we are just provided a connection string to write to the hub and nothing else. Coming to replicator , i see some topic called __confluent_command created in the namespace . I downloaded the confluent replicator from here https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-replicator . As mentioned am just sending a simple string "abcd" and it fails with record too large exception . Any idea what could be the reason ?

Comment: Replicator is free for a 30 trial, then will [require a license](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/license-configs.html). The command topic I thought was for ksqlDB, but it's been some time since I looked. In any case, I suspect that error comes from some event other than the `abcd` message. Regarding MirrorMaker, I think some of those heartbeat/offsets features can be disabled, but then you lose some reliance of failover. If you just want a plain migration script, I've seen people use Flink for this, or you can use the old MirrorMaker scripts

Comment: How do i find out what message is breaking the size constraints ? Also the requirement is to propagate messages from one kafka topic to an event hub as and when data arrives in the source topic and it's not a one time event . GIven this would replicator be the right choice ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer what exactly is old MirrorMaker scripts . With latest strimzi we have MirrorMaker2 by default , right ?

Comment: Replicator is one option, of many. Another one is [Booklin](https://github.com/linkedin/Brooklin/#use-cases). There's not really a way to know what's throwing the error without running tcpdump, I think. And I'm not talking about Strimzi (or k8s at all). https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330